MetroLog for C# Maui is null in a service
MetroLog is working very well for the pages but I tried to use the code in the example in my service or ViewModel class
private static readonly ILogger Log = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(nameof(DownloadService));

log is always null. Using the dependency injection, I can't have my code running. For example, I have this class
    public partial class ArticleService : RestServiceBase
    {
        public ArticleService(IdentityService identityService) : base()
        {
        }
    }

that it is based on this one
    public class RestServiceBase
    {
        protected RestServiceBase()
        {
        }
    }

In my MauiPrograg.cs I use the dependency injection like:
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new ArticleService(sp.GetRequiredService<IdentityService>()));

but I can't find how to pass an instance of the MetroLog.
